A custom decorator don't work with discord.py commands
I'm currently working on my bot in discord.py 2.0. Every time I create a new team, I need to check if the user is registered in the bot. If not, then send a request to register. Previously, I had to write this check in every new command. I considered this an unwise duplication of code and put this check in the decorator. But when I assign a decorator to a command, it is not added to the bot. She just doesn't exist. I have never encountered such a problem before. If anyone has encountered such a problem or has an idea what the problem might be, then I would be very grateful to hear it.
This is a class of commands.
from discord.ext import commands

from main import db

from scr.phrases_func import dict_to_str
from scr.cfg import phrases
from scr.command_author_check import command_author_check


class GeneralCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx):
        auth = ctx.message.author
        if db.check_user(auth):
            if db.get_user(auth).permissions_level >= 20:
                await auth.send(ctx.message.author.mention + phrases.master_greeting + dict_to_str(phrases.master_commands))
            else:
                await auth.send(ctx.message.author.mention + phrases.slaves_greeting + dict_to_str(phrases.slaves_commands))
        else:
            await auth.send(ctx.message.author.mention + phrases.general_greeting + dict_to_str(phrases.slaves_commands))

    @commands.command()
    @command_author_check()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ")


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(GeneralCommands(bot))

This is a decorator.
from main import db
from scr.cfg import phrases
from scr import phrases_func


def command_author_check(permissions_level: int = 1):
    print("command_author_check")

    def decorator(func):
        print("decorator")
        
        async def wrapper(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
            print("wrapper")
            auth = ctx.message.author
            if db.check_user(auth):
                if db.get_user(auth).permissions_level >= permissions_level:
                    return await func(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    await auth.send(ctx.message.author.mention + phrases.slaves_greeting + phrases_func.dict_to_str(phrases.slaves_commands))
            else:
                await auth.send(ctx.message.author.mention + phrases.general_greeting + phrases_func.dict_to_str(phrases.slaves_commands))
        return wrapper
    return decorator

I tried to call the command already decorated by the decorator discord.exe.command.commands in my decorator, but it didn't lead to anything.

The library already gives us a pretty simple way of creating custom checks and decorators, here's a quick example:
def command_author_check(permissions_level: int = 1):
    async def check_perms(ctx):
        auth = ctx.message.author
        if db.check_user(auth):
            return db.get_user(auth).permissions_level >= permissions_level
        return False
    return commands.check(check_perms)


@commands.command()
@command_author_check()
async def test(ctx): ...


# to handle the error
@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("whatever error message")


commands.check
Command.error
commands.CheckFailure

